# Python iterating over elements of a column in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Hi all new to python more used to matrix like software

I have a problem with iterating through a list of lists.

I've imported a csv file as a list of lists

```
['2004', '1', '7', '20', '50', '0', '8.92', '7.63', '9.84', '0.34', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '21', '0', '0', '9.4', '8.69', '10.04', '0.27', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '21', '10', '0', '9.14', '8.02', '9.75', '0.29', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '21', '20', '0', '9.12', '8.11', '9.75', '0.14', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '21', '30', '0', '9.09', '8.59', '9.75', '0.17', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '21', '40', '0', '8.85', '8.11', '9.56', '0.16', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '21', '50', '0', '8.86', '8.11', '9.46', '0.24', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '22', '0', '0', '8.72', '7.92', '9.36', '0.23', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '22', '10', '0', '9.01', '7.73', '10.23', '0.35', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '22', '20', '0', '9.45', '8.4', '10.42', '0.37', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '22', '30', '0', '9.14', '8.4', '10.13', '0.34', '2'],
 ['2004', '1', '7', '22', '40', '0', '9.04', '8.5', '9.94', '0.25', '2'],
 ...]
```

each row is a list of elements

I need to extract (filter) the rows of data from the file using 4th column (col 3 starting count at 0) as a criteria i.e. if  any element in 4th column is greater than 3 and less than 5 write that row to a new list and if any 4th column element is greater than 17 and less than 19 write this row to same new list also.

```
import csv

data = open('imput.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(data)
dataIn = []
for row in datareader:
dataIn.append(row) # reading in the data as a list of lists

dataFlt = []; #initialise new lists
data_vals = [];

for i in range(0,len(dataIn)):
if dataIn[i][3] >= 3.0 and dataIn[i][3] <= 5.0:
dataFlt.append(i)
elif dataIn[i][3] >= 17.0 and dataIn[i][3] <=19.0:
dataFlt.append(i)
```

This code runs without an error but returns an empty dataFlt list

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your column from a string to a float first:

```
column = float(dataIn[i][3])
if 3.0 <= column <= 5.0 or 17.0 <= column <= 19.0:
    dataFlt.append(dataIn[i])
```

I used comparison chaining to simplify your test, and I added the *row*, not the index, to `dataFlt`.

Your code could be simplified to filter *while reading*:

```
with open('imput.csv', 'r') as data:
    datareader = csv.reader(data)
    dataFlt = [row for row in datareader 
               if 3.0 <= float(row[3]) <= 5.0 or 17.0 <= float(row[3]) <= 19.0]
```

This produces the `dataFlt` list in one step, and doesn't build a `dataIn` list at all. If you do need a `dataIn` list for other purposes, just call `list()` on the CSV reader:

```
with open('imput.csv', 'r') as data:
    datareader = csv.reader(data)
    dataIn = list(datareader)

dataFlt = [row for row in dataIn 
           if 3.0 <= float(row[3]) <= 5.0 or 17.0 <= float(row[3]) <= 19.0]
```

Comment: As a note, if you want to do this for lots of ranges, it might be worth using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do it efficiently.

Comment: @Lattyware: provided the data is already sorted on that column.

Comment: Well, if not, you can always sort it first. Also, rather than converting each item to floats here, you can use the [`csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) option to let the `csv` module do the work for you.

Comment: @Lattyware: sorting can be expensive, for grouping unsorted data using a dictionary storing lists is far more efficient. `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` assumes that anything not in quotes is a float, but the data here appears to contain datetime stamps in the first few columns, so perhaps applying float to everything is not that helpful here.

Comment: It definitely depends on the case at hand. When I was talking about `groupby()`, I did mean specifically for lots of ranges, where the cost of iterating over the data lots of times to construct lists might be more than a single sort followed by the groupby.

Comment: @Lattyware: yes, if you need multiple passes where one sort and a groupby would do instead then groupby is efficient and great.

Comment: Surely it's less to do with the size of the input, and more to do with the constant time expensiveness of the multiple pass approach.  Sorting + groupby is O(nlogn) vs O(n) for multiple passes, so large ranges make multiple passes more attractive, no?

Comment: @zehnpaard: at some point the constant costs are going to add up enough to make it worth while for *specific cases*. But you are right, O(n) is still O(n) even when multiple passes are made.

Comment: Thank you all for prompt and comprehensive answers. All the answers did what I wanted them to do. I didn't want to sort the data so I used Martijn Pieters solution which gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings to floats, you need to cast to float:

```
for row in datareader: # just iterate over the datareader
    if  3.0 <= float(row[3]) <=  5.0:
        dataFlt.append(row)
    elif 17.0 <=  float(row[3]) <= 19.0:
        dataFlt.append(row)
```

Or:

```
if  3.0 <= float(row[3]) <=  5.0 or  17.0 <=  float(row[3]) <= 19.0:
      dataFlt.append(row)
```

You can also use filter to only keep the lines you want:

```
filter(lambda x: 3.0 <= float(x[3]) <= 5.0 or 17.0 <= float(x[3]) <= 19.0  , datareader)
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic for your answer I wasn't aware of this filter function cheers.